# indent XML text with Transformer

Tags: java, xml, formatting, indentation

I'm writing an XML file with the following code:

```
Source source = new DOMSource(rootElement);
Result result = new StreamResult(xmlFile);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

and this is the output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature-sequences>
<sequence>
<initial-frame>0</initial-frame>
<points>
<point>
<x>274.0</x>
<y>316.0</y>
</point>
...
```

I want this file to be indented, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature-sequences>
  <sequence>
    <initial-frame>0</initial-frame>
    <points>
      <point>
        <x>274.0</x>
        <y>316.0</y>
      </point>
...
```

the call to `setOutputProperty` in my code doesn't solve the problem, it actually makes the text with new lines (but not indented).

anyone has a solution to this, without the need of external libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to specify the amount of spaces to indent as well:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for! but I think this property name is very weird.

Comment: Glad it worked! The only reason I know about it is because I got bit by this myself. XML related APIs in Java are horrible in general.