# How to add a carriage return to XML output in Java

Tags: java, xml, carriage-return

In Java how do I output a carriage return in the resulting XML file, so that everything isn't on one line?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElement("requests");
doc.appendChild(root);
root.appendChild(request);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(file));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

The above code creates an XML file, but all on one line.

Comment: See if [this answer helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941826/java-1-6-javax-xml-transform-transformer-refuses-to-indent-xml-strings-which-co).

Comment: Do you have a schema that you are using to base the XML off of?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should fix the issue.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

Comment: while saving works as intended, loading the created file fails - how do you load an xml structure that has this output property. "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element"

Comment: Schifty, can you share your code so that people know the context you are talking and may be try out locally?

Answer (score 17):

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

First line add indents, second set indent value.

Answer (score 1):

After I spend some hours with this issue, finally I could solve the way I needed (to include a new line). The previous answers didn't work for me.

This way, I could include a new line:
`org.w3c.dom.Text nodeSeparator = doc.createTextNode("\n\n    ");`

And then, insert it before my desired node:
`parentNode.insertBefore(nodeSeparator, foundNode);`

Comment: Nice. In my case if I just edited existing xml and used the OutputProperty solution it could make some weird indents in the file. With this solution I can add newlines where ever I want in the xml. Thanks! I could also do my own indents with doc.createTextNode("\t").