# XML file cannot be imported into SOLR

Tags: xml, solr, import, format

I am very new to SOLR and still trying to figure it around.
I have some personal crawled data, and I use the my code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790146/create-xml-file-with-linebreaks) to convert it into SOLR's xml field format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<add>
<doc>
<field name="ID">1</field>
<field name="FULL_MESSAGE">[CNA] Independent adviser recommends shareholders accept offer for SingLand http://t.co/OEiftRyl7N</field>
<field name="SOURCE">CNA</field>
<field name="NEWS">Independent adviser recommends shareholders accept offer for SingLand </field>
<field name="LINK">http://t.co/OEiftRyl7N</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="ID">2</field>
<field name="FULL_MESSAGE">[ST] Australia's foreign minister updates PM Lee on reverse Colombo Plan http://t.co/bc7ZHCztW5</field>
<field name="SOURCE">ST</field>
<field name="NEWS">Australia's foreign minister updates PM Lee on reverse Colombo Plan </field>
<field name="LINK">http://t.co/bc7ZHCztW5</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="ID">3</field>
<field name="FULL_MESSAGE">[CNA] Grace Fu meets China�s NPC vice chairperson http://t.co/6k9CLe4c1x</field>
<field name="SOURCE">CNA</field>
<field name="NEWS">Grace Fu meets China�s NPC vice chairperson </field>
<field name="LINK">http://t.co/6k9CLe4c1x</field>
</doc>
.
.
.
```

But when I try to import the xml into SOLR, it kept giving me this error:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException
: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
```

I have absolutely no idea what this means. Is my XML not in the correct format? Or something else?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Here are the changes I made to schema.xml. However, it still produce the same error

```
<fields>
<!-- Custom Fields -->
<field name="ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="FULL_MESSAGE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="SOURCE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="NEWS" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="LINK" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
...
<fields>
```

Comment: Yes, your document is not valid XML document

Comment: Are you referring to the field names? Could you tell me what is the valid XML document?

Comment: I don't see closing tag </add>

Comment: There is closing tag </add>. Is just that the data are 10000 over lines long.

Comment: oh, i see. this dots are just confusing

Comment: My question has not been answered yet. Is it because the fields I have are not default of SOLR?

Comment: If you use standard schema.xml - yes, this is the reason

Comment: Hi. I added the fields in schema.xml, but the error still persist.       <field name="ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />   
  <field name="FULL_MESSAGE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
  <field name="SOURCE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="NEWS" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="LINK" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />

Comment: still same exception?

Comment: The error is still not resolved :(